# How can an EU citizen (Belgium) move to the US?

Tags: usa, visa, eu-citizens, eu, belgium

Barring marriage, how can one move to the US? I've been looking into it and the E3 visa for "skilled, professional and unskilled workers" is for Australian citizens only.

I'm asking for a Belgian citizen that can speak English, French and Flemish fluently and has two bachelor degrees... one in computer science/programming and another in 3d graphic arts.

The hoops one has to jump through to become a citizen in the US are numerous and I would like to know if there's anyone out there that managed to make it work for them.

Answer (score 7):

You will find detailed information about USA Visas in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_visa). Given your particular situation (Belgium citizen interested in working in the USA by no means of marriage), you may want to further research the H-1B and L1 visas. To my knowledge those two visas are the most common means to start working in the USA.

**H-1B**

> The H-1B classification is for professional-level jobs that require a minimum of a bachelor's degree in a specific academic field. In addition, the employee must have the degree or the equivalence of such a degree through education and experience. Before the H-1B petition can be filed with USCIS the employer must fill a "Labor Condition Application" (LCA) with the Department of Labor demonstrating that it is paying the required wage for this position in the geographic region where the job is located. The required wage for the position is the higher of the "actual wage" that is paid to other employees in this position or the "prevailing wage" which can be determined using nearly any source, including the employer's own wage survey.

**L-1 Intracompany Transferee**

> The L-1 classification is for international transferees who have worked for a related organization abroad for at least one continuous year in the past three years and who will be coming to the United States to work in an executive or managerial (L-1A) or specialized knowledge capacity (L-1B).

Comment: Another common way could be the Diversity Immigrant Visa program https://www.dvlottery.state.gov/