# How long can I wait to move after obtaining a green card?

Tags: usa, greencard

If I should get a green card in the lottery, how long can I stay in my home country before moving to the US, before the green card becomes invalid?

Comment: First of all, you can only become a permanent resident (get a green card) in the US. When you immigrate, you get an immigrant visa from a US consulate, and only when you enter the US using that visa, do you become a permanent resident. Are you asking about if you go to the US, get a green card, and then move back to your country?

Comment: Immigrant visas are valid usually for [6 months](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/immigrate/immigrant-process/interview/after.html), unless your medical examination will expire before that. On another page, it said you can petition to get an extension but it will need to be for a reason that's beyond your control.

Comment: So i will have to get a "regular" working visa before, then move to the USA and apply for or win a greencard? Edit: I just found [this post](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/how-can-an-eu-citizen-belgium-move-to-the-us?rq=1) which was very helpful. Thank you both!

Comment: No, you do not need a second visa if you win the DV lottery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you get your visa, it is valid for six months. Visas will only be issued during the financial year (October-September period) for which the lottery was held. Once the visa expires, if you didn't enter the US and convert it to a green card (i.e.: got a stamp on it at the port of entry) - it expires, and your win vanishes, you will no longer be qualified for the green card you've won.